# Remove Dynamically Added Controls from Userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have an Excel userform with dynamically added checkboxes.

I add the checkboxes with code that looks like this:

```
Set chkBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1", "Checkbox" & i)
```

I want to remove all of these checkboxes.

```
Dim j As Integer
'Remove all dynamically updated checkboxes
For Each cont In Me.Controls
    For j = 1 To NumControls
        If cont.Name = "Checkbox" & j Then
            Me.Controls.Remove ("Checkbox" & j)
        End If
    Next j
Next cont
```

I get the following error message:
[image: Error MEssage]

Comment: one of the problems here might be the paranthesese in " ("Checkbox" & j)"

Comment: check at wich j it fails and verify if this is a checkbox added at run time and NOT in design mode

Comment: Looking back, what probably fixed my code wasn't the check, but the exit for once it found the right one. @PatrickLepelletier is probably right, this is probably checking the wrong checkbox. That being said, Chris's code below should fix that issue either way.

Comment: i came back to this post, only to wonder why i didn't see it: i do this stuff with a `On error resume next`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A better approach may be to keep track of the controls you create (eg in a collection), and use that to remove them.

This way your code is not bound to the name format, and can be applied to other control types too.

```
Private cbxs As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set cbxs = New Collection
End Sub

' Remove all dynamicly added Controls
Private Sub btnRemove_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    Do While cbxs.Count > 0
        Me.Controls.Remove cbxs.Item(1).Name
        cbxs.Remove 1
    Loop
End Sub


' Add some Controls, example for testing purposes
Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim chkBox As Control
    For i = 1 To 10
        Set chkBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "SomeRandomName" & i)
        chkBox.Top = 40 + i * 20
        chkBox.Left = 20
        cbxs.Add chkBox, chkBox.Name  '- populate tracking collection
    Next

    ' Demo that it works for other control types
    For i = 1 To 10
        Set chkBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ListBox.1", "SomeOtherRandomName" & i)
        chkBox.Top = 40 + i * 20
        chkBox.Left = 60
        cbxs.Add chkBox, chkBox.Name
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Might as well change the variable *chkbox* name. +1 for the cool use of collection.

Comment: Thx @L42.  Yes, I would use i generalised name.  Just kept it to make it clearer to the OP how this relates to his original code

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion! In this particular application, I wanted to remove checkboxes that were created at runtime (and thus had that particular naming scheme), while leaving every other control alone. But you're right, this is cleaner, and more generic code. +1

Comment: i'm not sure but wouldn't a collection start at 0 ?

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier actually no, collection Items start at 1.  (Dictionaries on the other hand start at 0).  VBA can be quite inconsistent with starting indexes

Comment: @chis ok, im adding this to my personal notes :)

Comment: I spent ages trying to work out how to delete custom controls added at runtime to a PowerPoint form so this elegant solution is just the ticket. Thanks @chris.

Comment: Friendly hint: Assume the assignment to the collection in the 2nd loop should be coded as `cbxs.Add chkBox, chkBox.Name` (instead of `chkBox.Add ...` resulting otherwise in run time error 438 *Object doesn't support this property or method* :-) @chrisneilsen

`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there are no othe control names starting with "Checkbox",

```
For Each cont In Me.Controls
    If InStr(cont.Name, "Checkbox") = 1 Then
        Me.Controls.Remove cont.Name
    End If
Next cont
```

Comment: Nice approach, very simple but efective.

Answer (score 2):

if you already know the name of the controls, the type, and how many, why double loop ?

note that ONLY controls created at runtime can be removed.

```
'the following removes all controls created at runtime
Dim i As Long
On Error Resume Next
With Me.Controls
    For i = .Count - 1 to 0 step -1
        .Remove i
    Next i
End With
Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
```

and for your case : 'if all naming are correct

```
Dim j&
For j = 1 To NumControls
    Me.Controls.Remove "Checkbox" & j
Next j
```

and another approach that you can try

```
Me.controls.clear ' from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/clear-method-microsoft-forms
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a check for the control seemed to fix this. Not entirely sure why, but it works.

```
   Dim j As Integer
'Remove all dynamically updated checkboxes
For Each cont In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(cont) = "CheckBox" Then
        For j = 1 To NumControls
            If cont.Name = "Checkbox" & j Then
                Me.Controls.Remove cont.Name
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next cont
```

Comment: What's this loop inside the loop doing there?

Comment: The inner loop is checking the number of each control. In the outer loop, I got to control A, but I don't know with all certainty that it's control 1. So I check through every number until I find the right number.

Comment: It wasn't the check for control that fixed this, but rather the exit for--when I find what I'm looking for, I stop looking. It just so happened that my checkboxes were checked before anything else. The accepted answer is more stable; it doesn't rely on luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the original code using command buttons, and just added "Me.Controls.Count" rather than "NumControls" and defined "Cont" as a Control. It seems to be working for me. Please let me know if this works for you:

-->

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim Cont As Control
Dim C As Integer
'Remove all dynamically updated checkboxes
For Each Cont In Me.Controls
    For C = 1 To Me.Controls.Count
    If Cont.Name = "CommandButton" & C Then
        Me.Controls.Remove ("CommandButton" & C)
    End If
    Next C
Next Cont
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to select which controls are kept and which are deleted is to use the .Tag attribute. 
This allows some fine control of the controls as they are added, for example by using the .Tag as a bitfield.

At creation time:

```
With Me.Controls.add("Forms.Label.1", Visible:=True)
{code}
    .Tag = 1
{more code}
```

Then when the time comes to tidy up:

```
For Each C In Me.Controls
    If C.Tag = 1 Then Me.Controls.Remove C.Name
Next
```