# Ambiguous Userform name

Tags: excel, vba

I create Userform

```
  'Sub Crt_UserForm(ByVal count23 As Long, ByVal Temp As String, shts As Variant)
Dim myForm As Object
Dim Textbox1 As MSForms.TextBox
Dim Textbox2 As MSForms.TextBox
Dim Label1 As MSForms.Label
Dim Label2 As MSForms.Label
Dim Button1 As MSForms.CommandButton
Dim Button2 As MSForms.CommandButton

'Dim shtchk() As MSForms.CheckBox
Set myForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)
'Set myForm = CallByName(UserForms, "Add", VbMethod, "Test")
ReDim shtchk(count23) As MSForms.CheckBox

With myForm
 .Properties("Name") = "Test"  'Иногда эта строка вызывает ошибку
    .Properties("Caption") = "Выберите листы для защиты паролем"
    .Properties("Width") = 300
    .Properties("Height") = 150

End With

'For Each x In Me.UserForms
'If x.Name = "Test" & a Then
'Next x
    Set Label1 = Test.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Label1")
    Set Label2 = Test.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Label2")
    Set Textbox1 = Test.Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1", "Textbox1")
    Set Textbox2 = Test.Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1", "Textbox2")
    Set Button1 = Test.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "Button1")
    Set Button2 = Test.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "Button2")
With Label1
.Top = 10
.Left = 10
.Width = 50
.Height = 20
.Caption = "Текущий пароль"
End With
With Label2
.Top = 10
.Left = 70
.Width = 50
.Height = 20
.Caption = "Новый пароль"
End With
With Textbox1
.Top = 40
.Left = 10
.Width = 50
.Height = 20
'.Caption = "Новый пароль"
End With
With Textbox2
.Top = 40
.Left = 70
.Width = 50
.Height = 20
'.Caption = "Новый пароль"
End With
With Button1
.Top = 70
.Left = 10
.Width = 50
.Height = 20
'.Caption = "Новый пароль"
End With
With Button2
.Top = 70
.Left = 70
.Width = 50
.Height = 20
'.Caption = "Новый пароль"
End With
Test.Show
End Sub
'
```

after the actions are over, I delete the created userform:

```
Sub RemoveUserForm()
With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
    .Remove .item("Test")
End With
End Sub
```

First time it runs OK. But when I run it second time, it gives the error "Ambiguous name detected: Test" in the string:

```
Set Label1 = Test.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Label1")
```

So, somewhere deleted object myForm with the name "Test" is stored and prevents from creating the Userform object with the same name. How to fix it?

Comment: You may need `myForm = Nothing` or something similar (`Close/Unload`?) when you are done with it.

Comment: Personally I would suggest that you leave the blank form in the workbook to start with and then manipulate it as needed at run time. Changing a workbook project from within the same project usually causes far more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @braX myForm = Nothing doesn't help, I tried

Comment: I agree with what @Rory mentioned. (many eons ago, I learned this the hard way... :P ) But if you want to follow your approach so that you learn by making the mistakes then that is also ok with me :) Simply share the complete code. In the current code, `Test` object is not defined or initialized so it is difficult to suggest anything.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout , edited the post - entered the full code.

Comment: I don't see how that code works at all given that the form name is not Test.

Comment: Looks like it's `= "Test" & a` and not `"Test"`

Comment: @braX corrected - be sure that used "Test" name everywhere. Before edit I tried to randomize name, it didn't help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790320/remove-dynamically-added-controls-from-userform

Comment: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/vba/2014/3/3/vba-code-to-create-modify-delete-userforms

Comment: @braX  Bro, you really saved me! Beautiful! need to set controls different with ` Designer ' property as `Set Label1 = myForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Label1")` and call userform show via `VBA.UserForms.Add(s).Show`

Answer (score 0):

The solvation was in method of call to userform object via .Designer property `Set Label1 = myForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Label1")`
and method of userform show `VBA.UserForms.Add(s).Show`

```
Sub Crt_UserForm()
Dim myForm As Object
Dim s As String
Dim Textbox1 As MSForms.TextBox
Dim Textbox2 As MSForms.TextBox
Dim Label1 As MSForms.Label
Dim Label2 As MSForms.Label
Dim Button1 As MSForms.CommandButton
Dim Button2 As MSForms.CommandButton


Set myForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)


With myForm
    .Properties("Caption") = "Smth"
    .Properties("Width") = 300
    .Properties("Height") = 150


End With
s = myForm.Name

    Set Label1 = myForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Label1")
    Set Label2 = myForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Label2")
    Set Textbox1 = myForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1", "Textbox1")
    Set Textbox2 = myForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1", "Textbox2")
    Set Button1 = myForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "Button1")
    Set Button2 = myForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "Button2")
With Label1
.Top = 10
.Left = 10
.Width = 50
.Height = 20
.Caption = "SMTH"
End With
With Label2
.Top = 10
.Left = 70
.Width = 50
.Height = 20
.Caption = "SMTH"
End With
With Textbox1
.Top = 40
.Left = 10
.Width = 50
.Height = 20

End With
With Textbox2
.Top = 40
.Left = 70
.Width = 50
.Height = 20
'.Caption = "SMTH"
End With
With Button1
.Top = 70
.Left = 10
.Width = 50
.Height = 20
.Caption = "OK"
End With
With Button2
.Top = 70
.Left = 70
.Width = 50
.Height = 20
.Caption = "SMTH"
End With
With myForm.CodeModule
            x = .CountOfLines
            .InsertLines x + 1, "Sub Button1_Click()"
            .InsertLines x + 2, "MsgBox ""Hello!"""
            .InsertLines x + 3, "Unload Me"
            .InsertLines x + 5, "End Sub"
            
End With
VBA.UserForms.Add(s).Show
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove VBComponent:=myForm
End Sub
```