# Dynamic created labels how to delete before creating it

Tags: excel, vba

I am dynamicly creating labels here. But Before I creat I will delete them so reverse it. But it doesnt work. here my code:

I Also posted code part, where could be the problem. I would be happy to solve it.
I saw the problem, as i added new labels via TextBox and Commandbutton, where i save new datas to access database and than i refresh UserForm1_Initialize. I became dupplicates of buttons beacuse the deleting doesnt work.

```
Sub UserForm1_Initialize()
    Dim labelIndex As Long 
    labelIndex = 1 
    'database here
    Dim connStr As String
    connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Link to database;"

' ADODB-connection creat
    Dim conn As Object
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open connStr

    ' SQL-here
    Dim sqlQuery As String
    sqlQuery = "SELECT Feld1, Feld2 FROM ListeLink ORDER BY Feld1;" 'order 

        ' ADODB-commandsobjekt creating here
    Dim cmd As Object
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery

    ' ADODB-Recordset creataing here
    Dim rs As Object
    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    With UserForm1
        ' reverse here trying to delete the labels first so i dont have dupplicate if i add new labels with commandbutton and refresh it.
        Dim i As Long
        LabelIndex = 1

        For i = .Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If TypeName(.Controls(i)) = "label" Then
                If Left(.Controls(i).Name, 7) = "Label_" Then
                    .Controls.Remove i
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        Dim topOffset As Integer
        topOffset = 10 ' Startposition

        Dim myFrame As Object
        Set myFrame = .FrameButton

        ReDim labelEventsArray(1 To 1) 
        
    
    Do Until rs.EOF
        ' Label creating here
        Dim newLabel As MSForms.label
        Set newLabel = myFrame.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Label_" & labelIndex, True)

        ' giving Label-properties to my dynamic created labels
        With newLabel
            .Caption = rs.Fields("Feld1").Value
            .Left = 6
            .Top = topOffset
            .Width = 410 'width
            .Height = 20 'high
            .Tag = rs.Fields("Feld2").Value 'tag
            .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle 'style
            .TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter 'algn
            .FontSize = 10 'size
            .FontName = "Calibri" 'font
            Set labelEventsArray(labelIndex).LabelEvents = newLabel

        End With

        ' Create instance of Klasse1
        Set labelEventsArray(labelIndex) = New Klasse1

        ' Link Klasse1 to the newLabel
        Set labelEventsArray(labelIndex).LabelEvents = newLabel
        

        ' Expand dynamic array
        ReDim Preserve labelEventsArray(1 To labelIndex + 1)

        ' Expand dynamic array for labels (optional)
        ReDim Preserve labelArray(1 To labelIndex)
        Set labelArray(labelIndex) = newLabel

        ' Update position
        topOffset = topOffset + 22

        ' Next record in the recordset
        rs.MoveNext

        ' Increase the index on the count variable
        labelIndex = labelIndex + 1
        Loop
    End With

    ' close
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
    
   
    
End Sub
```

I think there is a problem with this part

```
    ' reverse
    Dim i As Long
    LabelIndex = 1

    For i = .Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If TypeName(.Controls(i)) = "label" Then
            If Left(.Controls(i).Name, 7) = "Label_" Then
                .Controls.Remove i
            End If
        End If
    Next i
```

How can i solve it?

---

Update with this code and debugging:

```
For i = .Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If TypeOf .Controls(i) Is msforms.label Then
            'MsgBox "test"
            .Controls.Remove i
    End If
Next i
```

Debugging
"runtime error 444

Controls could not be deleted, this method cannot be used in this context"

Comment: Is the inner if-clause ever executed (check with breakpoint, MsgBox, Degug.Print, ...)? Maybe the TypeName you are comparing is wrong (e.g. start with a capital letter)

Comment: You should learn to use the debugger - that would reveal the problem easily: The TypeName of the control is `Label` (with a capital L), not `label` .

Comment: You already have your solution from the above comments. There is one more way... use `If TypeOf .Controls(i) Is msforms.Label Then`. Here you do not have to worry about the case of the text as intellisense will take care of it...

Comment: @Shrotter and FunThomas, if isnt executing just test with msgBox "Test", the msgBox doesnt apear. Tested already with Capital L doesnt work.

Comment: @SiddharthRout can you maybe write the whole if clause? couldnt implement it, dont get msgBox for proof

Comment: As @FunThomas mentioned, use a breakpoint on the `For` statement and then step through the code pressing `F8` and see if the code is entering the loop.

Comment: @SiddharthRout  edited as you said and Updated my question with a debuging error can you maybe check?
how to use a breakpoint?

Comment: If you are not aware how to use breakpoints then check out this video [Error Handling & Debugging (Part 2) in Microsoft Excel 365 for Windows](https://youtu.be/1ZLuco1-klw)

Comment: What is `myFrame`? You are add new labels to `myFrame` but try to remove labels from the userform.

Comment: myFrame is a Frame where the labels dynamicly created I have a frame in userform1 this calls myFrame

Comment: @vbaguru So check if you can/want to remove the labels also from this frame not from the userform itself.

Comment: BTW @chrisneilsen has already demostrated how to do what you want in [Remove Dynamically Added Controls from Userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790320/remove-dynamically-added-controls-from-userform)

Comment: He is also removing from userform. Yes i guess my problem ist now, that i have to remove the labels from Frame (myFrame) im trying to do from Userform. But puh, ill try it now but would be also happy if someone can help

Comment: @vbaguru so loop over the _myFrame.controls_ and remove all labels.

Comment: Thanks all! it worked and i posted the code as answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Changed to code:
Removing the labels from frame not from userform was the answer and working with `If TypeOf .Controls(i) Is msforms.label Then`

```
.....
        Dim myFrame As Object
        Set myFrame = .FrameButton
        ' Vorhandene Schleife ändern
        For i = myFrame.Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If TypeOf .Controls(i) Is msforms.label Then
                    myFrame.Controls.Remove i
            End If
        Next i
......
```

Thanks to all who helped with commends.

Comment: Good Job on finding the solution yourself :)